# Rename and Replace Placeholder Task in Azure DevOps CI pipeline

Tags: file, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I searched it, but I am not able to find any out-of-the-box task for a build pipeline of AzureDevOps to perform the following tasks;

- file rename (in my case it's a Javascript file)
- replace placeholder like the following: #placeholder# inside the renamed .js file

Is there something available out-of-the box to perform this tasks?

[image]

Comment: Hi @OuterSpace, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi unfortunately I did not have time to try it, as I am involved in different projects. Hope to get back by next week.

Comment: Ok, if there are any updates, please feel free to let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For first part you can call simply from powershell/script task and [rename-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7):

```bsh
Rename-Item -Path "daily_file.txt" -NewName "monday_file.txt"
```

Or [mv command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-rename-files/) and bash task.

For the second part you may use [Token replace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

so let's say you have file `create-container-instance.sh`

```sh
az container create -g TheCodeManual --name myapp1 --image #{Image}
```

and in yaml

```yaml
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    targetFiles: 'stackoverflow/12-container-instance/create-container-instance.sh'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

and for that token `#{Image}#` is replaced by `Image` variable.

This is my pipeline:

[image]

Task group has task fro replacing tokens.

Here is variable declaration:

[image]

and token was replaced as expected:

[image]

If you want to use powershell to replace tokens you can try this

```bsh
function Replace-Tokens
{
  param(
        [string]$inputFile,
        [string]$outputFile,
        [string]$token,
        [string]$tokenValue
    )

    (Get-Content $inputFile) | foreach-object { $_ -replace $token, $tokenValue } | Set-Content $outputFile
    Write-Host "Processed: " + $inputFile
}
```

All credit goes to [Tim Hobson](https://gist.github.com/hoserdude/5808610)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try it. Is there some powershell command also for replacing tokens?

Comment: @OuterSpace yes, this is possible. Please check my edit.

Comment: I tried the replace variables task but even though the task gives no error it does not replace my tokens: e.g #PORTALAPPBASEURI# remains #{PORTALAPPBASEUR}I#. In the task i put #{ as token start and }# as token end. Can you point me to the right solution, please?

Comment: Please check my edit and code [here](https://github.com/kmadof/devops-manual/tree/master/stackoverflow/12-container-instance)

Comment: thank you for the yaml file. Where do I have to put the value to substitute to the placeholder? I tried using pipeline variables with the same name of the string contained in the placeholder but it does not work

Comment: Well, maybe you have a typo in variable name. Because this all what you have to do. It works with yaml and classic.

Comment: I think that the point is that I have used task group to group all the task and maybe the variables that I defined for the pipeline are not visible to the tasks contained in the task group. I am further investingating it.

Comment: So to make it clear. You have replace token task in task group, right? And variable defined in pipeline?

Comment: yes. that is the situation. I attached the screen of the repace token tasks. Actually it does nothing because I think it can find the variables